# Not understandable by SpringAop proxies behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm not been able to understand by the bold statements:

> The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the
>   main(..) of the Main class has a reference to the proxy. This means
>   that method calls on that object reference will be calls on the proxy,
>   and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of the
>   interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method
>   call. **However, once the call has finally reached the target object,
>   the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may
>   make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be
>   invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has
>   important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to
>   result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a
>   chance to execute.**

Code below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(new SimplePojo());
        factory.addInterface(Pojo.class);
        factory.addAdvice(new RetryAdvice());

        Pojo pojo = (Pojo) factory.getProxy();

        // this is a method call on the proxy!
        pojo.foo();
    }
}

public class SimplePojo implements Pojo {

    public void foo() {
        // this next method invocation is a direct call on the 'this' reference
        this.bar();
    }




    public void bar() {
        // some logic...
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that method call this.bar() is never intercepted by Spring AOP mechanism. So if any advice is associate with bar method is irrelevant in this case as it called from this.foo(). If you want to support proxying this type of request, you can not use Spring AOP, you have to go with  build time aop like AspectJ

Comment: but why is this so??

Comment: Can you show me the internal details inside the proxy class.

Comment: because spring does not know what is inside your method as it does not parse your methods. it works on metadata like method signature and annotation.

Comment: what details you want from proxy class. Here is one example [Link](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jdk-dynamic-proxies)